# How do I get Junit 4.10 to run from the command line on Windows without typing the path to every file?

Tags: command-line, junit, installation, classpath

I guess this is easy for everyone else but I cannot get junit to work from the command line.  I had no problem installing the java run time environment, but this junit install has more to it that I'm apparently not seeing.

My class path is:

```
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip.;set classpath=%classpath%;C:Program Files\JUnit\junit-4.6.jar;C:\Program Files\JUnit\
```

My windows path is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Teleca Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\Program Files\JUnit\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I can't get junit to run its test files or any file that I've written.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting stuff in the JRE lib/ext directory.  Learn how to use CLASSPATH properly.

If that CLASSPATH is an environment variable, you're learning something important: You don't need it.  The JVM, IDEs, and app servers all ignore it.

The right way is to use the -classpath option on javac.exe and java.exe when you compile and run.

You shouldn't be altering the PATH for every Java project, either.  Point it to the JDK/bin so you can access the tools you need, but that's all you should have to do.